# Is it Linear map $f: V \to V, f \circ f = f \Rightarrow V = f(V) \oplus \ker f$? Or only $\Rightarrow V \cong f(V) \oplus \ker f$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm supposed to show

$$\text{Linear map } f: V \to V, f \circ f = f \Rightarrow V \cong f(V) \oplus \ker f$$

However, I'm quite sure it's even

$$\text{Linear map } f: V \to V, f \circ f = f \Rightarrow V = f(V) \oplus \ker f$$

Right?

I'm not sure if this is a typo in the exercise text? Why would there be a "$\cong$" and not "$=$"?

Comment: Equality implies isomorphic so no problem there. But  there is the notion of internal direct sum and direct sum, look it up and that should make things clear.

Comment: @HelloDarkness "Equality implies isomorphic so no problem there." Of course, agreed. "But there is the notion of internal direct sum and direct sum, look it up and that should make things clear." I already did even before posting and still don't get why they would use "$\cong$". Can you elaborate a little bit further?

Comment: Of course! Let $E$ ve a vector space and $E = X \oplus Y$, where the sum is internal. So for every $a \in E$  $a= x + y$. Now we identify (this is an isomorphism) $a \in E$ with  $(x,y) \in X \times Y$, now we have that $E \cong X\oplus Y$ (here the sum ia nit internal). This happens because they differ as sets ($E \not \subset E \times E$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an idempotent linear operator $f$ on a vector space $V$ induces a decomposition $V=\textrm{ker }f \oplus \textrm{im }f$.

If $U,W$ are subspaces of $V$, and $V$ is isomorphic to the external direct sum $U\oplus W$, then it is customary to write $V=U\oplus W$ and call $V$ the internal direct sum of $U$ and $W$.

For example, consider the projection $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $f(x,y,z)=(x,y,0)$. Then $\textrm{ker }f=\{(0,0,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3\}\cong \mathbb{R}$ and $\textrm{im }f=\{(x,y,0)\in \mathbb{R}^3\}\cong \mathbb{R}^2$. From the internal point of view, we can say $\mathbb{R}^3=\textrm{ker }f \oplus \textrm{im }f $. From the external point of view, we can say $\mathbb{R}^3\cong \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Any idea why they would use "$\cong$" then?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct. I remember this result as “every idempotent linear operator is a projection”.

To prove $V$ is the sum of the two subspaces, we must show that every $v\in V$ can be decomposed to sum vectors in $f(V)$ and $\ker f$. Consider $f(v)$ and $v-f(v)$. Of course, $f(v)\in f(V)$. Since $f(v-f(v))= f(v)-f(f(v)) = f(v)-f(v)=0$, $v-f(v)$ is in the kernel of $f$.

In order to should that it is a (internal) direct sum, let $u$ be a vector in the intersection of two subspaces. $u\in f(V)$ implies there is a $w\in V$ such that $u=f(w)$, and $u\in \ker f$ implies $f(u) = 0$. As a consequence of these facts, we have
$$ u=f(w)=f(f(w))=f(u)=0$$
which is enough to conclude the final result:
$$ V = f(V)\oplus \ker f$$

Geometrically, we see that an idempotent operator projects the original space to its image (parallel to its kernel). Now that vectors are mapped to their destination, a repeated projection cast no more effects.

Comment: @integralette The proposition is correct if you change symbol, for spaces on both side are indeed isomorphic. However, I believe that equality reveals more information.

Comment: Yes, I agree. That's why I'm so confused about why they would write "$\cong$" instead...

Comment: @integralette But this did prove the exercise, isn’t it? I don’t know which textbook you are reading, but I guess the weaker result may be recalled after that page.

Comment: @integralette Or perhaps the writer wish you remember that equal vector spaces are isomorphic. They have the power to write in their still, and there is no need to get confused!